# Show notification every step of difference between two values

Tags: c#, math, timer

I have to answer this question that seems a riddle ... I don't know if there's a real solution or it's impossible...

Questions : Having two double values, one is the total amount of money in the safe, the other is threshold of maximum money recommended in the safe

For example: recommended value of money (threshold) : $1,500

Total amount is a variable that is calculated every 5 seconds by a timer, in this timer tick event i have the value of the recommended value of money and the value of the total amount of money in the safe.

At the timer tick event, I need to check if the value of total money is greater than recommended value, and show a notification to the user UI. But since the timer tick event happen every 5 seconds, I need to show a notification the first time that the total amount is greater than recommended amount, and every 50$ step of difference above the threshold.

An example (every row of this example is a timer tick event) :

```
Total : 1200$ − Recommended : 1500$   → No Notification
Total : 1505$ − Recommended : 1500$   → Notification (first overcoming of threshold)
Total : 1520$ − Recommended : 1500$   → No Notification 
Total : 1537$ − Recommended : 1500$   → No Notification
Total : 1558$ − Recommended : 1500$   → Notification (first overcoming of 50$ step)
Total : 1574$ − Recommended : 1500$   → No Notification
Total : 1586$ − Recommended : 1500$   → No Notification
Total : 1598$ − Recommended : 1500$   → No Notification
Total : 1612$ − Recommended : 1500$   → Notification (second overcoming of 50$ step)
Total : 1623$ − Recommended : 1500$   → No Notification
```

And so on. Is there a way (math calculation or algorithm) to show this notification knowing only this two value, without storing any other variable in memory ?

**I Can't store the "total amount" previous value in a variable.**

I don't know if there's a solution but someone have passed to me this question as a riddle.

Do you have any idea if is there a solution to this question ?

Comment: I find the question extremely confusing. What are the two values? 1500 and 50? And what exactly is the question? It looks like you can easily solve it if you keep the previous value (which for some reason you don't want to do), and I don't see how you can solve it without keeping the previous value...

Comment: I can't keep the previous value, i can only have three value : threshold (1500$), total amount(variable), overcoming threshold step (50$).

I can't store value of previous value :D

Comment: Those three values, are you allowed to modify any of them?

Comment: Step = fixed value (50$) ---- threshold = fixed value (1500$) --- total amount = variable value (calculated in timer tick event).

I can't change the fixed value : step and threshold.

Comment: Is the total amount a strictly-non-decreasing value?

Comment: No the total amount can decrease since user can deposit and take money from the safe.

Comment: Forget the steps, you can't even tell the **first time it went over the threshold**. You must be missing something here, because as Mark said, this is unsolvable, unless you're willing to allocate one extra `decimal`.

Comment: I think it's a bad question. What is meant by "without storing any other variable in memory"? Whenever you run any .NET program you are putting thousands of variables in memory whether you do so explicitly or not. The .NET framework uses variables all over the place. Any time you raise an event this will use some variables in memory to work out which handler must be called. Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: @Mark Byers - I completely agree. I had my eye on the close button, but wanted to give the OP another chance to explain the question.

Comment: maybe this isn't a question, it's a riddle ...  Then the answer of this riddle is unsolvable?

Comment: Alice sighed wearily. "I think you might do something better with the time," she said, "than wasting it in asking riddles that have no answers."

Comment: Is there a limit to how much money can you add or deduct from the safe during each 5 seconds interval? Also, can you provide an example on how the notification works when you deduct money? If this is a "trick question" from someone or somewhere, reproduce it here verbatim (ask him to repeat) lest you misquoted it somewhere.

Comment: The notification appear only when the total amount is greater than threshold, there's no notification when the total amount decrease from threshold. no there's no limit in how much money you can add or deduct to the safe.

Comment: @Kobi: That quote totally sums up my opinion of this question. Though from my point of view I should replace the word "asking" with "answering". I want my time back! :( I'm going to find another of your answers and upvote it because you deserve some rep - it is such a good comment that now I feel that participating in this question wasn't a *complete* waste of my time.

Comment: In case your question change or you want to keep thinking about it, I'll let you know that you if you can negate threshold and step, you have 2 booleans and 4 possible states they can represent. Given your current constrains (or rather, lack of constrains), I doubt 4 states is enough.

Comment: Since it is tagged C# and you mention the UI. Perhaps your colleague is trying to hint that some UI's allow the value displayed to be read back again from the UI instance. These are of course stored in memory, although they will not require an additional variable to be declared.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the $1500 because you're outputting that. You need to know the value coming in. You also need to know the previous context, otherwise you don't know what to do with a call like

NotifyOrNot($1537)

So wherever it's stored, you need that context. There are probably ways to do it with the number of notifications, with a delegate returned from the delegate you called originally, with differences between the values, etc. - they're just different ways of storing that context. You still need a 3rd piece of memory. Or even a 4th, since you're also storing the step difference of $50.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is homework. I'll removed all comments because of that. You'll need to figure the code out by yourself.

```
public class ExampleApp
{
    private int _currentMoney = 1450;
    private int _lastNotificationStep = 29; // 50 * 30 = 1500

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] argv)
    {
        var app = new ExampleApp();
        app.InYourLoop(50);
        app.InYourLoop(30);
        app.InYourLoop(40);
    }

    public void InYourLoop(int deposited)
    {
        int total = _currentMoney + deposited;

        var currentStep = (int) Math.Floor(total/50d);
        if (_lastNotificationStep != currentStep && total >= 1500)
        {
            for (int step = _lastNotificationStep; step < currentStep; ++step)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Notification of step: " + currentStep + " for total " + total);
                _lastNotificationStep = currentStep;
            }
        }

        _currentMoney = total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show N notifications, where `N = (currentMoney - recommendedMoney)/step` where step = 50?

Comment: This would show multiple notifications per tick. `every row of this example is a timer tick event`

Comment: That is intended and stated in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You said you can't store the last total amount in a variable, but can you store other things?  I'd think you'd only need the NextThreshold value.

```
int NextThreshold = 1500;
while (true)
{
  int CurrentBalance = GetNextBalance();
  if (CurrentBalance > NextThreshold)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("You spent too much, foo");
    while (NextThreshold < CurrentBalance)
      NextThreshold += 50;
  }
}
```